# Парсинг сайта при помощи CsQuery

Tags: c#, парсер

Разбираюсь с парсингом сайтов при помощи `CsQuery`, возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Как одновременно доставать несколько элементов с сайта? Например, я хочу взять имя и город человека. Пока что научился по одному элементу брать:

   ```
   CQ dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl($"{nedv}");
   foreach (IDomObject obj in dom.Find(".item-contacts-link"))
   {
       if (obj.GetAttribute("href") != "")
       {
           string number, name;
           number = obj.GetAttribute("href");
           //textBox2.Text += urls + System.Environment.NewLine;
           Console.WriteLine($"Номер: {number}");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Если код сайта написан не очень красиво (вместо подключения стиля он указывается в `div`)
   пример:

   ```
   <div style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px; border-top: 1px solid #e3e2df; display: block;">
       <span style="font-size: 18px; color: #666">Витебск</span>
       <span>
           <span style="font-size: 16px; color: #666; padding-left: 30px;">Адрес: ул. Ленина, 3а </span>
           <br>
       </span>
   </div>
   ```

   Как мне правильно доставать в таком случае город?

[Пример сайта](https://avitoby.com/2-komnatnaya-kvartira-327/kvartira-na-sutki-ul--centralnya-5-minsk-1184.html)

Comment: 1. Я не думаю, что за раз можно получить и имя, и город, ведь в HTML они в разных местах, в разных блоках. Это, по сути, как в магазине, хлеб в одном месте, а молоко в другом и вам так или иначе нужно будет пойти и взять сначала одно, а потом другое. Так что вам скорей всего придется сначала получить имя, потом получить город, телефон и т.д. Что касается 2-го вопроса, то найдите закономерность, вон читаемый HTML я вам сделал, что видите? Есть `div`, в нем два `span`, где в первом город, во втором адрес. Ну так берите смело первый `span` и из него текст.

Comment: Я `CSQuery` не использую, но запрос должен быть примерно такой `div > span:first-child`, далее просто читайте `.InnerText`.